# Still encounter Exception after remove android lib in adt when debug java class,what should I do?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In my class , I use some classes of internet access library such as HttpClient etc:

```
`import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;`
```

I am trying to test a java class in my android , but get this Exception:
[image: firstly , this alert window shows]

in console, printed these below:
    
        `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/HttpClient
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more`

I have remove android library in this class's run configuration.
Except running as Android Application to debug, how can I configure my eclipse?

Comment: you don't need to add any external lib for this

Comment: @Dipu I did't add external lib for this class , just suspect that these exceptions resulted from my importing classes ,which is contained by android library but not in JRE.